# Golang type assertion for pointer to slice

Tags: go, type-assertion

Is there a better way for that?

```
var collection []string
anyFunc(&collection) // valid
anyFunc(collection) // invalid
anyFunc(nil) // invalid
anyFunc("test") // invalid

func anyFunc(collection interface{}) error {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(collection)
    if rv.Kind() != reflect.Ptr || rv.IsNil() || reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(collection)).Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        return errors.New("Invalid collection type, need pointer to slice.")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Full example at [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/WytOtXmf56N)

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/q4hlv8aQmGU ?

Comment: without reflection it is not possible, isn't it?

Comment: You could use type assertion instead of reflection if you know what kind of slice, however if any kind of slice, then no, not without reflection.

Comment: ok, i don't know the concrete type. thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The text of this answer was originally written by [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva)]

```
func loadData(collection interface{}) error {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(collection)
    if rv.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && rv.Elem().Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        return nil  
    }
    return errors.New("Invalid collection type, need pointer to slice.")
}
```